# VSTS Build Agent with sudo

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, sudo

My company is using VSTS builds for continuous integration. Every commit triggers a build which runs on a Linux agent. The problems is after the build is finished, I need the agent to restart a service(which requires root). How can I automatically restart the service via the agent with minimal security risks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new user to build agent machine and grant the necessary security to restart service, then configure/change the build agent running account to that user.

An article about [deploying an agent on linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-linux).